# Why is it possible to call multiple methods on an object?

Tags: python, oop

How are commands like (pseudocode, e.g. ndframe from pandas) `someObject.group().sum()` possible?
Does `(someObject.group())` return the new object where `(...).sum()` is then executed?

Comment: It returns the instance it was called on for method chaining.

Comment: Call `someObject.group()` on its own and see what you get back?

Comment: Method chaining, see Wikipedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method that returns `self`, which allows you to chain method calls together:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Dog(object):
    def bark(self):
        print("bark!")
        return self

    def eat(self):
        print("snarf!")
        return self

fluffy = Dog()
fluffy.eat().bark()
```